# Windows account ending with $

Tags: windows, windows-domain

A Windows account that looks like this "domain\computername$". What does that mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the computer account.  When a computer joins a domain it has to have an account associated with it in order to apply policy settings.  This gets created automatically when the computer joins.

From Microsoft's [technet article on accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759279%28WS.10%29.aspx):

> Computer accounts
>
> Every computer running Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows XP, or a server running Windows Server 2003 that joins a domain has a computer account. Similar to user accounts, computer accounts provide a means for authenticating and auditing computer access to the network and to domain resources. Each computer account must be unique.

Comment: Aha. What's the connection between computer and user accouts? Lets says I give a computer account access to login to a database, who can login to the database? The computer itself? All domain users that are also local users on the computer?

Comment: no, computer accounts aren't used for that sort of access control - they are used for domain level - is this computer allowed to access the domain?  What computer-level group policies should be applied to it, etc.

Comment: >"computer accounts aren't used for that sort of access control"   OK, I understand that you shouldn't do this, but what if you do? I'm using a sql server, where this the computer account is used.

Comment: I guess there's nothing stopping you from doing it, but I suspect it would allow access to any user on the computer (which may be desirable I guess), but all with the same access level.  I'm not too hot on MS SQL myself, so I don't know all the implications of this.

Comment: @Karsten: “Lets says I give a computer account access to login to a database, who can login to the database?” – Windows services running under system accounts (SYSTEM, NETWORK SERVICE, possibly others).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some sql databases using this way. which is not a Standard practice. All domain users that are also local users on the computer can access.. Which leaves less control to sql admins. Instead using a service account is advisable.

Comment: I very much doubt regular users can impersonate the computer account. The computer account is only usable for the SYSTEM account.

Comment: I have seen the construct in which **IIS ApplicationPoolIdentities** gain access to a SQL Server through the computer account. Although these are not regular users, this may not be what you want.